# Android ActivityNotFoundException failing to catch on Intent in OS 4.1.2 (works on 4.0.3)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, exception, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Thanks for taking a look. I am a very old programmer but absolute newbie to Android/Java. Although I haven't found a way to make code colorful and pretty here yet ;).

I am starting an activity to open a file with a bogus/fake extension (mime type) so I can force this **ActivityNotFoundException** exception (*to test*).

Somehow, this exception never happens on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (*OS 4.1.2*). Adobe Reader opens up and errors that the file is not a PDF (*it's not*). However on an older ASUS Transformer tablet running 4.0.3 the exception is caught properly.

The code in question is like so:

```
// this file exists (check omitted).. 
File docFile = new File("/path/to/file.bogusextension");

// intent
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// getting doc Uri
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(docFile);

// getting doc mimeType
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUrl);
String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);

// this is for an adobe native extension, just getting FREContext
// in the class below and mapping functions
DocLauncherExtensionContext extensionContext = (DocLauncherExtensionContext) context;
Activity activity = extensionContext.getActivity();

try
{
    activity.startActivity(intent);                 
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(context.getActivity(), "This never happens!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 
}
```

Is there anything blatent wrong with this code that would allow a file with any extension what-so-ever to be constantly thrown at Adobe Reader? I have cleared my defaults (Settings->Application Manager->Reset). Everything I startActivity is just hurled at Adobe Reader.

Any thoughts appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

needs to become:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

You were putting data and an ActionCode into the intent, however you never told it what it was an intent for.

Comment: The next line down didn't configure that? (intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);). I tried your suggestion and it worked! I wonder why setAction() didn't configure it properly. Either way, it works great now, thank you!

Comment: The `setAction()` method is used for passing an action code into the Activity. This would be used if you had a custom activity that could do multiple actions, you could tell it what you need it to do. You need to create a new Intent, using the `ACTION_VIEW` activity.

Comment: Perhaps just being too new at the language, it seems like a nuance that people 'in the know' will understand. The overloaded constructor must simply operate differently if you choose an alternate version of it such as specifying the activity as you did rather than the no-argument constructor. setActivity() clearly isn't the same thing as setting this in the constructor. As much as I can tell is it definitely fixed it. Thank you!